# Solution to a specific form of Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

In my textbooks, I can't seem to find a solution for the differential equation of the form:
$$y' = 3t*\sqrt y$$
**How do I solve this differential equation?** Can I classify this equation as a Bernoulli Differential Equation, with $n=1/2$?

Comment: It's a separable differential equation. Integrate $\frac{dy}{\sqrt{y}}=3dt$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From

$$\frac{y'}{2\sqrt y}=\frac32t,$$

you draw

$$\sqrt y=\frac34t^2+C,$$

$$y=\left(\frac34t^2+C\right)^2.$$

Note that $y=0$ is also a solution.

Also note that a square root is positive, so that $\dfrac34t^2+C>0$ must hold. When $C<0$ this limits the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need to? The equation is seperable
$$ \frac{y'}{\sqrt{y}} = 3t $$

which integrates to
$$ \sqrt{y} = \frac{3t^2}{4} + c $$